# log4j starts writing bytes of zero value to log file

Tags: log4j

We are using log4j of version 1.2.16 which is using RollingFileAppender. Everything seems to work fine. But sometimes the log file gets corrupted.

Here is what happens. The beginning of the log file contains a lot of bytes with zero value - that is hexadecimal zeroes. After that the messages set by application follow. Now, if I just flush the log file and do something in the application, the zero bytes appear again and again. After restarting the server itself the logs are working fine for several days, but then again zero bytes come up.

UPDATE. I came to the solution which seems to work. This is how we do the rotation of logs now.

```
7za a -m0=lzma /opt/glassfish/domains/domain1/old-logs/`date +logs_%Y-%m-%d.7z` /opt/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/*
rm /opt/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/*.log*
```

And it seems to work fine, log4j does not give any troubleshooting over that.

Comment: Do you use `logrotate` in addition to `RollingFileAppender`?

Comment: No I don't. However, I found out that it happens on one single server, not at others, and the script for flushing the log there actually differs a lot from the others. I guess, this problem will go away after that

Comment: Would be interesting to know if you could fix it. We are currently experiencing a similar problem and it's hard to track down.

Comment: The way I see it, this happens if some other process (besides log4j) interferes with the files it writes to. We'll monitor for 3 days more and if this bug does not reproduce anymore, I'll post down the way we get rotate logs on our server without a problem.

Comment: I posted a solution for the problem.

Comment: … doesn't log4j write logs in the `/opt/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/` directory, while rotating? As far as I understand, that should be exactly the problem.

Comment: This is what's happening: Some external application is truncating the file, log4j still ends up writing at the previous buffer seek position, basically filling all values from 0 to seek-1 with null (zeros).